# What are the side effects of setting the timestamp in the PE-header to 0?

Tags: windows, pe, binary

The PE-Header of Windows executables contains as its third field the "Timestamp at compile time". To reach reproducibility in our build process we would like to set the time (Epoch seconds) to zero (=1970-01-01 00:00:00).

Does this have any side-effects? According to

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164151

the header does not impact the function.

Are there compiler/linker flags to get this automatically?

Kind regards
Stefan S.

Comment: though i see jason stating that windows doesn't care about time stamp i vaguely remember it is used for binding or some such things scrape oldnewthing by raymond chen for timestamp you should land the tidbit

Comment: I think this is what you're thinking of, @blabb: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100318-00/?p=14563/

Comment: @blabb: Yes, but that's for DLLs and Stefan is asking about EXEs. Nonetheless, I'll update my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: @BrendanDolan-Gavitt yes that is the article  jason you are welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this have any side-effects?

No, the Windows loader doesn't care about the timestamp in an EXE's PE header.

> Are there compiler/linker flags to get this automatically?

No, Visual C++'s `link.exe` does not have a command line switch for specifying the timestamp to use. (And Visual C++'s `cl.exe` doesn't apply since the PE timestamp is a linking timestamp, not a compiling timestamp.)

Comment: http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/ might be interesting for you, On what the windows loader uses.

Comment: @stolas, this one is more up-to-date: http://pferrie.host22.com/misc/tiny/pehdr.htm